# ios - how to make sure when I submit an app, only the iPhone part of it gets submitted?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am working on a new app. I am half-done with the iPad part of it, and I do not want the iPad part of it to go into the current version of the app. This will be the first version.

Where do I specify to Apple that I only want the iPhone version go to live?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project info in Xcode, do this:

[image]